# Angular router redirects all router to blank page

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I have setup my angular router in a very simple way but none of the routes load any components and no matter what I do they all redirect to '' and load a blank page. The app-root component loads the nav bar at all times but none of the other routes work.

**app.routing.module.ts**

```
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '/home' }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

// Import Material UI Components
import {MatButtonModule, MatCheckboxModule} from '@angular/material';
import {MatToolbarModule} from '@angular/material/toolbar';
import {MatCardModule} from '@angular/material/card';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { ProjectsComponent } from './projects/projects.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    ProjectsComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatToolbarModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app.component.html**

```
<!--The content below is only a placeholder and can be replaced.-->
<div style="text-align:center">
    <mat-toolbar color="primary">
      <span><img width="150" alt="Blitz Logo" src="../assets/blitz_logo_2014_v1_.png"></span>

      <!-- This fills the remaining space of the current row -->
      <span class="fill-remaining-space"></span>

      <span>A Link</span>
    </mat-toolbar>
  </div>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

> Note: when loading the default route it instantly redirect to `/home`
>   but then instantly redirects back to `''`, which is blank. Manually
>   typing in `'/home'` also instantly redirects to `''`, which is blank.

Comment: where is the  routerLink="/heroes" ?

Comment: i am just typing the routes into the browser atm, none of them work

Comment: Can you please recreate your problem in this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-d9xy79?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp-routing.module.ts and use dashboard instead of home and edit your post ?

Comment: It should work: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hrppg1. It looks like there is something else in your project that affects this. Modify my sample. Also check if you have any errors in the browser console (F12).

Comment: Did you import `@angular/router` in your `app.routing.module.ts` file?

Comment: What's in `HomeComponent`, As per you **note** it looks like the navigation happens to 'home' and then goes to blank..

Comment: Do you have the `base` tag in your `index.html` file? If so, what's it? It should be `<base href="/">`.

Comment: Sorry for late response. I rebuilt this project from scratch and it works. No idea what was missing. I imported the router in app.module.ts, do not include any routing in HomeComponent, but a base href in index.html. That being said... neither does the project that works. This was a wierd one.

Answer (score 0):

### Suggested corrections:

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';

const routes: Routes = [
// [CORRECTION] The order in the array (here) is important.
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '/home' }
];

/*@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }*/
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

// Import Material UI Components
import {MatButtonModule, MatCheckboxModule} from '@angular/material';
import {MatToolbarModule} from '@angular/material/toolbar';
import {MatCardModule} from '@angular/material/card';

// [CORRECTION] Import the array from app-routing.module.ts
import { routes } from './app-routing.module';
// [CORRECTION] Import RouterModule like this
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
// import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { ProjectsComponent } from './projects/projects.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    ProjectsComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    //AppRoutingModule,
    // [CORRECTION] Add the imported array here like this
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes),
    //--
    MatButtonModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatToolbarModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Should work fine now.